# MonoGame+HLSL: Using tex2Dlod throws "invalid DCL" exception when building the .fx file

Tags: shader, monogame, hlsl

I'm trying to access a texture in my vertex shader. tex2D can't be used inside a vertex shader, so I tried tex2Dlod instead. But then the effect file doesn't build anymore using the MonoGame content pipeline tool, showing me a *"invalid DCL register type for this shader model"*. I use OpenGL and the VS and PS shader model 3_0 cause higher versions do not seem to be supported by OpenGL.

Did someone have success accessing a texture in a vertex shader using Monogame and OpenGL? Is that even possible?

Here is the shader code, which sole purpose is to get that effect build with tex2Dlod working:

```
#define VS_SHADERMODEL vs_3_0
#define PS_SHADERMODEL ps_3_0

texture2D StateMap;
sampler2D StateMapSampler = sampler_state
{
    Texture = <StateMap>;
    MinFilter = POINT;
    MagFilter = POINT;
    MipFilter = POINT;
    AddressU = CLAMP;
    AddressV = CLAMP;
};

struct VertexShaderInput
{
    float4 Position : POSITION0;
};

struct VertexShaderOutput
{
    float4 Position : POSITION0;
};

VertexShaderOutput MainVS(in VertexShaderInput input)
{
    VertexShaderOutput output;

    output.Position = input.Position;

    float4 coord = float4(input.Position.x, input.Position.y, 0, 0);
    output.Position += tex2Dlod(StateMapSampler, coord); // the build only fails, when this line is included

    return output;
}

float4 MainPS(VertexShaderOutput input) : COLOR
{
    return float4(0,0,0,0);
}


technique Technique1
{
    pass Pass1
    {
        VertexShader = compile VS_SHADERMODEL MainVS();
        PixelShader = compile PS_SHADERMODEL MainPS();
    }
};
```

The issue seems to be known (https://github.com/MonoGame/MonoGame/issues/1813), but no solution provided yet, other than using a higher shader version, which I can't, because of OpenGL.

I'm using the latest MonoGame Version (3.8).

Comment: On Windows, DX11(vs_4_0) is required to use samplers in vertex shaders.  Assuming your code manually rewritten in GLSL can run on the target platform, you can compile it and package the resulting bytecode into an XNB file.  I have no clue how to do this, hence the comment, but I know it is possible, since this is exactly what MoJoShader does when targeting OpenGL.

Comment: There is a monogame patch that uses ShaderConductor instead of MoJoShader. That does support SM4 and SM5 on OpenGL. The source is available here: https://github.com/cpt-max/MonoGame/tree/shaderconductor. This is slated for MonoGame 3.9 see https://github.com/MonoGame/MonoGame/pull/7345